# udhcpd init.d script makes trouble using RPi as WiFi AP

Tags: init.d

I wrote an udhcpd init script. It is more or less like the standard script, which also made trouble. However it supports at least a status output. 
The problem is that it does not start automatically at boot and I don't know why. If I start it after boot, everything is fine and my AP is working. However I want to use my RPi for a quadcopter project and not as a SSH toolbox.

Disabling/Enabling yields the following messages:

```
pi@navio-rpi /etc/init.d $ sudo update-rc.d udhcpd disable
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `udhcpd' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `udhcpd' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
pi@navio-rpi /etc/init.d $ sudo update-rc.d udhcpd enable
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

This is the script.

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          udhcpd
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start busybox udhcpd at boot time
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/udhcpd
NAME=udhcpd
DESC="very small Busybox based DHCP server"
PIDFILE=/var/run/udhcpd.pid

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

# Include defaults if available
if [ -f /etc/default/udhcpd ] ; then
        . /etc/default/udhcpd
fi

if [ "$DHCPD_ENABLED" = "no" ]; then
    echo $NAME: Disabled. Edit /etc/default/udhcpd to enable it.
    exit 0;
fi

set -e
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --start --verbose --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
                --oknodo --exec $DAEMON
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --verbose --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
                --oknodo --exec $DAEMON
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;

  status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME"
        exit $?
        ;;

  restart|force-reload)
        $0 stop
        sleep 1
        $0 start
        ;;
  *)
        N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: I have never seen a space in the `#! /bin/sh` line - I've always seen it written without the space like so `#!/bin/sh`. Not sure if this has anything to do with it. Also, the LSB default runlevel warning are just warnings, they are not errors.

Comment: I cannot get udhcpd run at startup. I just use monit now to check this script for its status. I think it is not elegant but seems necessary.